# iterators in Unordered (or Hash) Maps

Tags: java, c++, hashtable, unordered-map

As far as I understand, Hashmaps are preferable to standard maps because you can find elements in close to O(1) time. This is done by using a hash or the key as an array lookup. We then resolve any collisions and pull out the value.

This works great for lookup, but if our array-space into which we do the hash lookup is sparsely populated, how does the hashmap/unorderedmap efficiently iterate all the elements in our hashmap without exhaustively going through our array-space?

Edit: yet Boost, SGI and C++11 hashmaps/unordered maps have iterators, so how do they work?

Comment: Sidenote: Java `Map` implementations (including `HashMap`) also provide iterators for keys, values and entries.

Comment: In certain cases it is possible to see degraded performance.  For example, `while (!map.empty ()) map.erase (map.begin ());` is `O(n²)`, not `O(n)` as one would expect.  (Though some implementations specifically track first occupied bucket to solve this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a parallel structure (for example a linked list as in a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)) it can't: iteration will need to check each bucket for content.

So if your buckets are *very* sparsely populated, this *can* become a factor. That's one of the reasons why you don't want to choose a bucket count that is *too* high (the bigger one obviously being wasted memory).

Comment: but most hashmap containers have iterators, how do they work?

Comment: By iterating over the buckets (and the linked lists that usually build the content of a bucket), I'd guess. It might not be the fastest thing possible, but it definitely works and is usually Fast Enough™.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration is O(n), where n is the capacity (i.e. the number of buckets) of the map. But normally, you shouldn't have a capacity of 100000 to store 6 keys. This means that O(size) should be O(capacity), which means that iteration is also normally O(size).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `O(n+m)` where `n` is the capacity and `m` is the number of entries? At least when the hash table uses chaining for colisions. In the worst case it would need to check `n` buckets and follow `m-1` links to find all entries.

Comment: The normal case is to have no collision. And O(n+m), in the worst case, is O(2n), which is still O(n): it increases in a linear way.

Comment: Actually, in the worst case without rehashing `m` could be bigger than `n`. But I see what you're saying.